# Nonparametric estimation of ranking data

Tags: nonparametric, ordinal-data, ranking

Suppose I have $\{X_i, Y_i, N_i\}$, where $N_i$ is the number of objects for sample $i$ (typically 30 - 35 objects), $Y_i$ is complete ranking (ordering or permutation) of $N_i$ objects, and $X_i = (X_{i1},\cdots, X_{iN_i})$ is a vector of attributes of each object.

I assume $Y_i = h(X_i+e_i, N_i)$, where $e_i =(e_{i1},\cdots,e_{iN_i})$ and each $e_{ij}$ is standard normally distributed and independent across $i$ and $j$.

I wonder if there is a way to estimate function $h$ non-parametrically.